# How to export an existing CodePipeline to CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

This is more of a lack of understanding on my part but I cannot seem to debug this.
I have created an codepipeline which runs terraform apply ( which internally creates the aws infrastructure for me ). the codepipeline seems to be working.

I need to implement the same codepipeline for another account, how can I do so.

I tried to get the json script using the below command.
`aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name`

I convert json script to yaml script.

When I try to run the yaml script on another account I get below error

`Template format error: At least one Resources member must be defined.`

**ISSUES**:
1.) Best Way I can export codepipeline to cloudformation template
2.) The approach which I used didn't work, how to solve it?

```html
{
    "pipeline": {
        "name": "my-code-pipeline",
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws-account-id:role/service-role/AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-aws-region-my-code-pipeline",
        "artifactStore": {
            "type": "S3",
            "location": "codepipeline-aws-region-45856771421"
        },
        "stages": [
            {
                "name": "Source",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Source",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Source",
                            "owner": "ThirdParty",
                            "provider": "GitHub",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "Branch": "master",
                            "OAuthToken": "****",
                            "Owner": "github-account-name",
                            "PollForSourceChanges": "false",
                            "Repo": "repo-name"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "inputArtifacts": [],
                        "region": "aws-region",
                        "namespace": "SourceVariables"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "codebuild-for-terraform-init-and-plan",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "codebuild-for-terraform-init",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Build",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CodeBuild",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "ProjectName": "my-code-pipeline-build-stage"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [],
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "region": "aws-region"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "manual-approve",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "approval",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Approval",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "Manual",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "NotificationArn": "arn:aws:sns:aws-region:aws-account-id:Email-Service"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [],
                        "inputArtifacts": [],
                        "region": "aws-region"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "codebuild-for-terraform-apply",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "codebuild-for-terraform-apply",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Build",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CodeBuild",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "ProjectName": "codebuild-project-for-apply"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [],
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "SourceArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                        "region": "aws-region"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "version": 11
    },
    "metadata": {
        "pipelineArn": "arn:aws:codepipeline:aws-region:aws-account-id:my-code-pipeline",
        "created": "2020-09-17T13:12:50.085000+05:30",
        "updated": "2020-09-21T15:46:19.613000+05:30"
    }
}
```

The given code is the yaml template that I used to create cloudformation template.

Comment: Where is the rest of the template?

Comment: @Marcin, trying below command
```aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name```
gave me template in json format , converted into yaml and this is what I get.

Comment: @Marcin, Is there some steps you would recommend in order to get the cloudformation template for the sample codepipeline. ( I wish to use the same pipeline in multiple accounts as well as multiple regions and best option seems to have a cloudformation template already created.

Comment: You have to create such template manually or look at third party tools, e.g. Former2.

Comment: @Marcin , I looked at third party tools eg former2 but it gives the same issue.
doing it manually is the only option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name` CLI command returns information about the pipeline structure and pipeline metadata, but it is not the same format as a CloudFormation template (or the resource part of it).

There is no built-in support for exporting existing AWS resources to create a CloudFormation template, though you do have a couple of options.

1. Use [former2](https://former2.com/) (built and maintained by AWS Hero, Ian Mckay) to generate a CloudFormation template from the resources you select.
2. Take the JSON output from the `aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name` command you used and manually craft a CloudFormation template. The pipeline will be one resource in the list of resources in [the full template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-anatomy.html). The info it contains is pretty close, but needs some adjustments to conform to the CloudFormation resource specification for a CodePipeline, which you can find [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codepipeline-pipeline.html). You'll also need to do the same for other resources that you need to bring into the template, with `aws <service name> describe`.

If you go with option 2 (and even if you don't), I recommend using [cfn-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-lint) with your code editor to help adhere to the spec.

Comment: This was helpful. I went ahead with option-2. 
only problem is it requires me to have the resources already created.
So, when I want to run the template in an aws account, it requires me to have certain resources already available.